# How do I redirect after_sign_up_path_for to a create action of another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

So I have `OrdersController#Create`, that I would like the user to be redirected to right after they register (so it can do some post-registration stuff).

Before I implemented the registration part of this workflow, this is what the `link_to` for that resource looked like:

```
<%= link_to 'Submit to Scheduling', orders_path(cart_id: @cart), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "primary button btn" %>
```

So basically, I would like to achieve the above functionality (including passing the `@cart` object as a param), but automatically from within the `Devise::RegistrationsController#Create`.

I am using Devise, and so I have created a `/users/registrations_controller.rb` and in that controller I am doing this:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    orders_path(cart_id: @cart)
    super(resource)
  end
```

When I did the above, it successfully created the user and redirected me to `Orders#Index` which is not what I want, see the logs below:

```
 User Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "company_name", "company_title", "phone") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "abc3@test.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$ZC2X2vCXd5JwVO"], ["first_name", "Test"], ["last_name", "User 3"], ["created_at", "2020-01-22 06:16:11.358863"], ["updated_at", "2020-01-22 06:16:11.358863"], ["company_name", "Acme Inc"], ["company_title", "CFO"], ["phone", "9876543210"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14:in `create'
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/orders
Completed 302 Found in 162ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms | Allocations: 6383)


Started GET "/orders" for ::1 at 2020-01-22 01:16:11 -0500
Processing by OrdersController#index as HTML
```

I even tried `orders_path(cart_id: @cart, method: :post)` and that didn't work.

How do I achieve what I am trying to do?

**Edit 1**

So I discovered `url_for` and it ALMOST gets me there, but doesn't quite work.

This is what I have:

```
url_for(controller: '/orders', action: 'create', method: :post, cart_id: @cart.id, only_path: true)
```

This is what happens:

```
↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14:in `create'
  User Create (5.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "company_name", "company_title", "phone") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "abc2@test.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$ezj6"], ["first_name", "Test"], ["last_name", "User 2"], ["created_at", "2020-01-22 07:26:09.589560"], ["updated_at", "2020-01-22 07:26:09.589560"], ["company_name", "Acme Inc"], ["company_title", "CEO"], ["phone", "9876543210"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14:in `create'
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14:in `create'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@myapp/gems/devise-4.7.1/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:187: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@myapp/gems/i18n-1.8.1/lib/i18n.rb:195: warning: The called method `t' is defined here
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/orders?cart_id=10&method=post
Completed 302 Found in 307ms (ActiveRecord: 13.2ms | Allocations: 8600)


Started GET "/orders?cart_id=10&method=post" for ::1 at 2020-01-22 02:26:09 -0500
Processing by OrdersController#index as HTML
```

So it still doesn't work. It is still sending me to `OrdersController#Index`.

Comment: What was the behavior before your change? Did it redirect you to another path or it created a new resource?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `super(resource)`.

In my understanding, you want to redirect to orders_path(cart_id: @cart) with `post` method. It's so weird. `after_sign_up_path_for` should return a some_path, which accessed by `get` method.

You can try another way, perform another action from another controller. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143216/12336104) will helpful to you.

Comment: So the `url_for` method is very close to what I want. The issue is that I need to also pass the `@cart` instance variable. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't pass an instance variable like `@cart`, but you can pass id of `@cart` and refind with the id.

Comment: How do I pass the method? I want the `create` action of the `orders_path` route to be hit, not the `index`. Even though I have specified `create` in the action, it is still going to `orders#index`. In other words, I want to send the same resource with a `method: :post` to `orders_path` and have it be sent to `Order#Create` and not `Order#Index`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
  request.params.merge!(cart_id: @cart.id)
  controller_you_want = OrdersController.new
  controller_you_want.request = request
  controller_you_want.response = response
  controller_you_want.create
```

Did you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that your code is returning the original value of the method, not the new path:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  orders_path(cart_id: @cart)
  super(resource)
end
```

Returns the overridden method, since you are calling `super(resource)` as the final expression in the method, and its result gets returned by your defined method.

If it is necessary to call super at all, because the overridden method does something more than just return a string, then either return the order of the calls, or return the value of `orders_path` with a variable.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  res = orders_path(cart_id: @cart)
  super(resource)
  res
end
```

You should check the method being called by super though, as it is possible you can just remove this completely.

Without seeing the rest of your code it is impossible to say whether `@cart` actually has a value, or is in fact just `nil`. You should check that it has been set in the controller prior to the `after_sign_up_path_for` method being called.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Devise::Controllers::StoreLocation#store_location_for`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FStoreLocation:store_location_for) which is used to redirect back after signing in.

```
store_location_for(current_user, new_order_path(cart_id: @cart))
```

This stores the location is the session. You can fetch the value with `stored_location_for`.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || super
end
```

However you can't/should not redirect to the create action. Create responds to POST requests. Redirects are always GET requests. Before you go adding a `GET /posts/create` route remember that GET should not be used for non-idempotent actions. Meaning that a GET request should not create or alter any resources.

If you break this rule your users could have a really bad day when they hit the back button.

And no you don't want to store and repeat the post action. Have the user submit the form - save the record and then redirect. Add a flag to the record if needed to mark it as "not finshed". Redirect the user back to the `edit` action and then "finish the order" by performing a PUT or PATCH request (update).